# Trying to write a query in toad to calculate sales commission

Tags: sql, oracle11g, toad

First thanks for your time and help. I am very new to toad

I am trying to write a query that will calculate total commission based on commission rate and total sales. I'm trying to use an IF statement to set the value of 'Rate' and use this to multiple based on the salemans name and total sales for the month that are pulled from a database. Any help or direction would be very much apprciated

```
Declare
Rate Number
;

Select 
SaName,
Sum(AMT)*Rate,
Count(Actno)

From RCVMGR.RCV_ACT_DAILY

Where (SaName = 'Mike' or SaName = 'Dave' or SaName = 'Tony') 
and ref1= 'PMT' and (SaDT between add_months (Last_day(sysdate-1),-1)+1 
and trunc(sysdate-1))

If SaName = 'Mike' Then
Rate = .15
elseif SaName = 'Dave' Then
Rate = .12
elseif SaName = 'Tony' Then
Rate = .1
End IF

Group by
SaName,
AMT,
ACTNO
```

Comment: Are the commission rates on a table somewhere? If so you should probably join to that table, rather than specify every single one in a case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select saname,
       sum(amt) * case
         when saname = 'Mike' then
          .15
         when sanme = 'Dave' then
          .12
         when saname = 'Tony' then
          .1
         else
          0
       end as commission,
       count(actno)
  from rcvmgr.rcv_act_daily
 where saname in ('Mike', 'Dave', 'Tony')
   and ref1 = 'PMT'
   and sadt between add_months(last_day(sysdate - 1), -1) + 1 and
       trunc(sysdate - 1)
 group by saname
```

However it would be best to join to a table holding the commission rates, if such a table exists.